# Prove that $\gcd(3^n-2,2^n-3)=1$ if and only if $\gcd(6^n-4,2^n-3)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

> Prove that $\gcd(3^n-2,2^n-3)=1$ if and only if $\gcd(6^n-4,2^n-3)=1$ where $n$ is a natural number.

I was thinking of using something with the Euclidean algorithm, but I still don't see how to take into account the fact that the gcd is $1$. We know that $3 \nmid 3^n-2$ and both $3^n-2$ and $2^n-3$ are odd, so that may help.

Comment: If you have a gcd equalling one, you can express 1 = ua + vb, where the gcd of (u,v)= 1. This is called bezout's lemma, have you tried using it ?

Comment: @wesssg Can you tell me how to use it to prove this statement?

Comment: GCD(3n−2,2n−3)=1 ----> Then, we have 1 = $a$( $3^n-2$ ) + $b $ ($2^n-3$ )= $1$

Comment: @wesssg How does that prove the question?

Comment: I'm working with this, I offered it as something that may be useful in case you hadn't considered it. GCD(3n−2,2n−3) = 1 ----> Then, we have 1 = $a (3^n-2)$ + b$(2^n-3)$= $1$, and then, we may manipulate this expression, (I'm not sure it will lead anywhere though)

Comment: Um... n = 3.  $(3^3 - 2,2^3 - 3) = (25,5) = 5 \ne 1$ but $(6^3 -4,2^3 -3) = (212,5) = 1$.  So not true. ????

Comment: Oh, my God. How many times must this greatest common divisor of $3^n-2$ and $2^n-3$ be asked in two days?!

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=3^n-2$ and $B=2^n-3$. If $n\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, $\;5\mid \gcd(A,B)$ by Fermat's little theorem.
We have $AB+3A+2B=6^n-6$ and $2\nmid B,\; 3\nmid A$, hence:
$$ \gcd(A,B) = \gcd(6^n\color{red}{-6}, 2^n-3).$$

Comment: How do you know that $\gcd(A,B) = \gcd(6^n-6, 2^n-3) \neq \gcd(6^n-4,2^n-3)$?

Comment: @Puzzled417: how many numbers can divide both $6^n-6$ and $6^n-4$? How many of them can divide $2^n-3$, too?

Comment: Jack, in case of considering further effort: this OP currently has 196 questions, and the two answers listed are to (his?) own questions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused.

If $n = 3$ then $\gcd(3^n - 2,2^n - 3) = \gcd(3^3 -2,2^3 - 3) = \gcd(27-2,8 - 3) = \gcd(25,5) = 5$.

But $\gcd(6^3 -4,2^3 - 3) = \gcd(216-4, 5) = \gcd(212,5) = 1$.

So the statement is not true.

?????